# Value "ErrorSync_one" at "ansr_A" of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Tags: android, json, android-volley, jdedwards

its me again, this time i have on Android a Volley Exception caused by the Json I receive. I look for similar questions but a learn it could be for multiple reasons.

This is the Json i send:

```
{
   "Branch  1":"1010901",
   "2nd Item Number 1":"2 T",
   "Or Ty 1":"WO",
   "Order Number 1":"454678",
   "Loc LE1 1":" ",
   "UM  1":"PC",
   "Lot Effectivity Date 1":"15\/12\/2023",
   "Expired Date 1":"15\/12\/2033",
   "Memo Lot 2  1":"454678",
   "Memo Lot 1  1":"15\/12\/2023",
   "Lot Serial Number 1":"LOTE100",
   "Complete Date 1":"15\/12\/2023",
   "Quantity Shipped 1":"12",
   "Reason Code 1":"T01"
}
```

my code request, its a POST method:

```
JsonObjectRequest objectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST,
                Url.VALIDATOR_URL, obj, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                Log.d("JSON response -->", response.toString());
                try {
                    if (response.getJSONObject("ansr_A").has("ErrorSync_one")){
                        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Principal.this);
                        builder.setTitle("¡ERROR!")
                                .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_error)
                                .setMessage("Record not inserted error. (A)")
                                .setPositiveButton("Accept", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                                    }
                                });

                        AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                        dialog.show();
                    }
```

and this is the response i get from the request:

```
{"ansr_A":"ErrorSync_one"}
```

But at the same time ends with the message of the exception that captures:

```
Value ErrorSync_one at ansr_A of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

I even did tests on Postman and everything seems normal.

[PostmanTest](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XG3kU.png)

Can someone help me please? I have to mention that I use on headers **Basic Auth** and **ContentType/JSON** . I also use Oracle JDEdwards as back for my project.